# How to perform a checksum on a row

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

is there a way to perform a checksum on a row using ms access? I need to compare two queries for equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built into Access to return a checksum for a row. What I've done in the past to verify that the data in two rows are identical is a union of a left and right join on all fields. It's a pain if there's many fields to type, but it works. You could also code you're own MD5 hash in VBA and return that in a query.